# Android page control like book?

Tags: android

I want to develop page control like **book**,means when user drags over page(left or right) control  will **move next page or previous page(with view also move)**, depending on which way the user dragged using their finger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid)'s `PagedView` UI element, it does exactly what you want