# Create a view carousel

Tags: android

I'd like to create something like a carousel with views. A continuum queue with an indetermined amount of the same type of view (just like a list), but when swiping left/right, (or up/down) it would move to the next/previous view (I could be cool if it did that with an animation, too). Plus, I also need to move though it by buttons. For example, "move to view 20".

Could you give me an advice on what to use for my purpose? Thanks in advance

**Edit:** By the way, grey big thing in the picture represents the current view, while the other thinner rectangles are the preceding and following view.

[image: Carousel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look on this answer [Android page control like book?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728950/android-page-control-like-book/6728996#6728996)

You can make gaps between pages with setting margins or padding.